# What does DirectorySynchronizationOptions.PublicDataOnly mean?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

There is a PublicDataOnly member in the DirectorySynchronizationOptions enum.
On MSDN it says "Do not return private data in the search results".

What does the "private data" here means?

I tried to get all users with DirSync in given domain with and without this PublicDataOnly option and set the PropertiesToLoad as "*". Same set of attributes and users are returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it from the AD technical spec:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223347.aspx

PublicDataOnly has no effect :).